# Unable to execute sonar job from jenkins 403

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am unable to do code analysis from jenkins,I am getting 403 error.The Execute Analysis permission is provided for all the sonar users,sonar administrator and project creators,but still iam getting 403.

In jenkins job i have used goal sonar:sonar

Am i missing anything in the configuration?

Error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project core: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.config.Settings: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories: You're only authorized to execute a local (preview) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this? what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've granted permissions to Anyone to perform analysis, then you will continue to have this failure because you're not providing credentials. Instead:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=analysis_token_here
```

Where the value of the login parameter is a [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token)

Comment: In global permissions i have provided execute analysis for anyone.Is there any other configuration?i have also tried to provide the sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=ReplacedWithToken but still iam getting the same error.

Comment: @Ravi double check the permissions on that particular project.

Comment: Hi Ann,I havent specified any project specific permission configuration in Sonar server.I am trying to execute code analysis from jenkins and push it to sonar server.

Comment: I have updated the permission screen shot in https://github.com/ravi21588/SO/blob/master/Sonarpermission.JPG